# generics in java with interface

Tags: java, generics, java1.4

I am having an interface with following definition :

`public interface genericInterface<E implements Comparable <E>>{
}`

and I want to write a class which implements this interface and will provide provide an arraylist implementation.

`public class MyClass<E> implements ***genericInterface<List>{***`

but list and comparable are obviously not compatible... i don't have any option for comparable. What should i write in place of ?

Comment: You can have several constraints - `E extends Comparable & Whatever`. However, I don't understand what you want to accomplish here - you want the list _items_ to be comparable or the list itself?

Comment: what do you mean by - "will provide an arraylist implementation"?

Comment: This isn't particularly clear; you don't have any option but to provide a type which implements `Comparable`...

Comment: Do u want your elements in the list to be comparable.That makes sense!!

Comment: Seems like you want `implements genericInterface<E>`.

Comment: I have to simulate partial ArrayList class functionality like add, remove, comapre 1 arraylist to another and some basic functions.
Our main contraint is we have to write comparable in interface def.. that is requirement.

Comment: @user1079065 Why do you need that interface then? Just make your class extend the `ArrayList` class, and override the methods?

Comment: @user1079065 Hmm, why do you need a "GenericInterface"? Imagine that doesn't exist .. do you need this MyList to *be* Comparable or only *accept* Comparable items?

Comment: @ Rohit Jain .. yeah I know... we are not allowed to do that... as I said before we have to implement partial arraylist class as the functionality..
it will provide some function declarations which we have to implement in myClass so that we will perform similar function to arraylist functions

@ user2864740 --- I have to write comparable to the interface. I cannot change that. what I can change is the class definition.

Comment: What exactly is actually comparable? The *lists* (you said you want to compare one list with another; if so, how) or the *elements* of the lists? Your interface should denote a list you're later implementing in your class?

Comment: Generics and java 1.4?